# Django Change Form FIlter

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How to create field filters for the Django change form in admin site?  The list filter seems to be only applicable to the change list. This is for Django version 1.9.x.

Answer (score 0):

Download admin_tools from
   https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools
and adminsortable from https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable

or just use

```
pip install django-admin-tools
pip install django-admin-sortable
```

in your INSTALLED_APPS include:

```
'admin_tools',
'admin_tools.menu',
'admin_tools.dashboard',
'admin_tools.liststyle',
'adminsortable',
```

So then if you have, say, a model Profile in your models, in your admin.py

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ['username', 'email',
                                    'name', 'is_cleared',
                                    'first_name', 'last_name',  
                                    'cell_phone','business_phone',                                       
                                    'address1','address2',
                                    'address2','zip','state','city',
                                    'country']}),)

    list_display = ('id','username', 'email',
                                    'name', 'is_cleared',
                                    'first_name', 'last_name',  
                                    'cell_phone','business_phone',                                       
                                    'address1','address2',
                                    'address2','zip','state','city',
                                    'country')
    list_editable = ('username','email','first_name','last_name','address1','address2') 
    search_fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name','address1','address2')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Profiles'
```

Of course, adjust the fields to match your model.